# My simple QTableView code crashes

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I wrote a simple code to try and learn about QTableView. When I build my project it doesnt give any errors but when I try to run it says:

> C:\Users\Eren\Documents\build-QTableViewUygulama-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug\QTableViewUygulama.exe exited with code 255

or

> The program has unexpectedly finished.
>
> C:\Users\Eren\Documents\build-QTableViewUygulama-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug\QTableViewUygulama.exe crashed.

I have some knowledge about C++ but I dont know much about Qt. I have no idea why I keep getting this error. Here is my code

```
//Class Model(aracmodel.cpp)
#include "aracmodel.h"

AracModel::AracModel(QObject* parent = 0) : QAbstractTableModel(parent) {

}

int AracModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const {

return 3;

}
int AracModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const {

    return Araclar.size();
}
QVariant AracModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const {

    if(role != Qt::DisplayRole && role != Qt::EditRole) return 0;

    const Arac& arac = Araclar[index.row()];

    switch(index.column()){

        case 0 : return arac.id;
        case 1 : return QString::fromStdString(arac.marka);
        case 2 : return QString::fromStdString(arac.model);
        default : return 0;
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QVariant AracModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int 
role){

    if(orientation != Qt::Horizontal || role != Qt::DisplayRole) return 0;

    switch(section){

        case 0 : return "ID";
        case 1 : return "Marka";
        case 2 : return "Model";
        default : return 0;
    }
    return QVariant();
}


//Class Model (aracmodel.h)
#ifndef ARACMODEL_H
#define ARACMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include "arac.h"

class Arac;

class AracModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    QList<Arac> Araclar;

    AracModel(QObject*);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex&) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex&) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const override;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role);
};

#endif // ARACMODEL_H



//Class Header arac.h
#ifndef ARAC_H
#define ARAC_H

#include <string>

class Arac
{
public:
    int id;
    std::string marka;
    std::string model;

    Arac(int, std::string, std::string);
};

#endif // ARAC_H

Arac::Arac(int i, std::string ma, std::string mo) : id(i), marka(ma), model(mo){} //This constructor is in arac.cpp



//MainWindow.cpp (only copying the parts i've changed)
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}




//MainWindow.hh(only copying the parts i've changed
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    AracModel* model;
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

Comment: From quick inspection I could not see any `model = new AracModel ( this);`, where do you initialize your model?

Comment: I think you should check if index is less than items in the list before accessing it   const Arac& arac = Araclar[index.row()];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate model pointer using :

> model = new AracModel(this);

before setting this model to tableView.

Have a look at this simple example:
http://www.thedazzlersinc.com/source/2012/06/04/qt-qtableview-example-short-and-quick/

Comment: one thing important not highlighted in this example is that the call to ui->setupUi(this)  must be done BEFORE the call to ui->tableView->setModel(model);

Maybe this is not obvious for beginners with Qt creator